# ScrollView keeps pushing textfields off view

Tags: ios, swift3, scrollview, textfield

This is the overall layout of the screen. The button is inside the scroll view, so that when the first responder appears the button will be pushed up to the users view. Then back down when the first responder resigns

[image]

In the second picture is what it looks like when the first responder is present. The button does move up, but now the text field is pushed off of the screen. If there is a way to allow the button to move up without the textfields being pushed off the screen, that would be amazing.
[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var TextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!

func closeKeyboard(){
self.view.endEditing(true)
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:            UIEvent?) {
closeKeyboard()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(scrollviewtest.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(scrollviewtest.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you using `AutoLayout`? How are you moving the views up? Post the code from where you are moving the views up.

Comment: Why don't you set frame when you Present responser

Comment: Post some code, then only somebody can figure out any solution but if buttons and `UITextField` are on the same `UIScrollView`, then you have to re-set frame `UIButtons`.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I updated the question with the code. Is the solution around setting the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like this for change frame of textfield,

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    var scrollContentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(320), height: CGFloat(345))
    self.scrollView.contentSize = scrollContentSize
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var kbSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! String).cgRect().size
    var contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height + 100, 0.0)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    var keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! String).cgRect().size
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {() -> Void in
        var f = self.view.frame
        f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height + 50
        self.view.frame = f
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {() -> Void in
        var f = self.view.frame
        f.origin.y = 0.0
        self.view.frame = f
    })
}
```

Comment: It's giving me an error for "var kbSize" and "var keyboardSize" both errors saying " Value of type 'String' has no member 'cgRect' "

Comment: CGRectFromString("some string")